# Configuring iptables rule

Tags: iptables

I have private cloud with eucalyptus and xen. Generally while creating an instance, eucalyptus tries to contact meta data service at 169.254.169.254. But here in my setup, the service is running at 192.168.1.10. Now I want to forward all request to this ip.

I want to create pre routing rule to forward all packets from 169.254.169.254/32 (port 80) to 192.168.1.10:8773.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 169.254.169.254/32 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.10:8773
```

This is the rule you have to place in Iptables.

hope that helps.